# Stats on questions upvote rate by tags

Tags: discussion, tags, voting, statistics

It seems to me that questions on the `C`, `C#`, `Java` tags are the ones getting upvotes more quickly.

Is there some kind of statistics about it?

Thanks!

Comment: If you know SQL, you can create a query to find out [here](http://odata.stackexchange.com). One caveat, though, is that vote timestamps are anonymized such that the resolution is only to the day. This will likely affect the results of your computations, as voting activity is generally highest when the question is asked, and trails off quickly as time goes on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There already is a [query for it](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/26/most-rewarding-tags-to-answer-among-the-tags-with-1000-questions).  The result may surprise you:

```
Tags                   Upvotes Answers Avg Upvotes / Answer 
---------------------- ------- ------- -------------------- 
language-agnostic      164055  29596   5.54                 
coding-style           37282   8215    4.54                 
haskell                21877   4988    4.39                 
functional-programming 22820   5240    4.35                 
programming-languages  66388   15507   4.28                 
user-interface         34885   8349    4.18                 
career-development     46397   11231   4.13                 
scala                  22378   5605    3.99                 
books                  42476   10741   3.95                 
resources              16243   4302    3.78                 
perl                   81379   22972   3.54                 
f#                     14997   4304    3.48                 
syntax                 24165   6977    3.46                 
stl                    22816   7246    3.15                 
vim                    23263   7515    3.1                  
development            16481   5388    3.06
```

C is 2.74, C# is 2.02 and Java is 1.91.  Avoid mentioning a language :)

Comment: Now a dead link, sadly.